# How can I edit the resulting String?

Tags: java, string

If the exception occurs I need to cut the resulting String by a value obtained in another method.

I have a resulting method :

```
private String generateSomeName() {
        String basicProjectName = "Sth_" + method1();
        return basicProjectName + "_" + "X" ;
    }

    private String method1() {
        try {
            Class.getNumber();  //returns String1 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.warn("Unable to get this Number", e);
        }
        return "";            
    }
```

My problem is that when everything works I will get the proper format of the String `Sth_String1_X`

But if there is an exception and I will get the empty String "" (without String1) my result is:

`Sth__X` (with double _)

And I need it to be:

`Sth_X` with only one _

Any tips how to handle this?

Comment: Add the first underscore inside `method1()` ?

Comment: Maybe you want to do `return Class.getNumber(); ` ?

Comment: You don't return `getNumber` at all

Comment: what is "Class" supposed to be?

Comment: I am returning Class.getNumber() when everything is ok and the method will return String - giving the expected result. Problem is when I assume that this method will not be able to return any String and throws exception - than I will receive only empty String and have to figure out how to cut the resulting one leaving it with only one "_" :) Tried almost everything, nothing works as expected :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming java 8 is used, an option would be to use `Optional` to add the `_` before the result returned by the `method1` method only if the result is not null and non empty

```
private String generateSomeName() {
    String basicProjectName = "Sth" + Optional.ofNullable(method1())
                                              .filter(s -> s.length() > 0)
                                              .map(s -> "_" + s)
                                              .orElse("");
    return basicProjectName + "_X" ;
}

private String method1() {
    try {
        Class.getNumber();  //returns String1 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.warn("Unable to get this Number", e);
    }
    return "";            
}
```

Comment: That would be brilliant but unfourtunatelly this method will never throw null. It will give either the String or Empty String. The problem is how to cut the final result when empty String will be given in return of the method 1.

Comment: @Anna then filter out the empty string by adding `.filter(s -> s.length() > 0)` before mapping the string. I've updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

```java
private String generateSomeName() {
        String basicProjectName = "Sth_" + method1();
        return basicProjectName + "X" ;
    }

    private String method1() {
        String output="";
        try {
            output=Class.getNumber()+"_";  //returns String1_ 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to get this Number "+e);
        }
        return output;            
    }
```